# How can I merge two dataframes of dissimilar size and preserve their column order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the dataframes

A:

```
g    N    a
1    3    5
2    4    6
```

and B:

```
g    N    a   e
3    3    4   7
4    9    1   8
```

Is there some way to merge these such that the resultant dataframe is:

```
g    N    a   e
1    3    5   NaN
2    4    6   NaN
3    3    4   7
4    9    1   8
```

In other words, is there some way to preserve the column order rather than re-sort lexicographically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reindex_axis`:

```
pd.concat([A,B]).reindex_axis(B.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   g  N  a    e
0  1  3  5  NaN
1  2  4  6  NaN
0  3  3  4  7.0
1  4  9  1  8.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I neglected to mention that was merging multiple dataframes, so the merge command was much more inconvenient than this reindexing operation.

Comment: Very neat solution ! It's really difficult (if possible) to top it

Comment: @MaxU,@COLDSPEED... Thank yall(Texan for you all, the plural of you.).

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes, the devs at StackOverflow are such control freaks that you can't accept the answer until some amount of time has passed.

Answer (score 2):

When merging, specify `sort=False`.

```
In [1251]: A.merge(B, how='outer', sort=False)
Out[1251]: 
   g  N  a    e
0  1  3  5  NaN
1  2  4  6  NaN
2  3  3  4  7.0
3  4  9  1  8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick: `pd.concat([a, b])[b.columns]`

Full test code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

a = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
g    N    a
1    3    5
2    4    6
"""), sep=r"\s*")

b = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
g    N    a   e
3    3    4   7
4    9    1   8
"""), sep=r"\s*")

pd.concat([a, b])[b.columns]
```

This produces:

```
   g  N  a    e
0  1  3  5  NaN
1  2  4  6  NaN
0  3  3  4  7.0
1  4  9  1  8.0
```

You might also want to reset the index:

```
pd.concat([a, b])[b.columns].reset_index(drop=True)
```

... in order to remove index duplicates. This gives:

```
   g  N  a    e
0  1  3  5  NaN
1  2  4  6  NaN
2  3  3  4  7.0
3  4  9  1  8.0
```